# Can't display image in listview from database mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, listview

I will display the image in listview android from mysql database using php, json but the image can't be displayed. link_image should show the location of the image to be but it does not display a valid location. Please help me. Thank you

```
status.php
<?php
    //  array for JSON response 
    $response = array(); 

    //  include file koneksi.php 
    include_once("connect.php"); 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status order by id_status desc");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
$response["data_status"] = array();

while($baris = mysql_fetch_array ($query))
{
    $id_status=$baris['id_status'];
    $status=$baris['status'];
    $id1=$baris['id_user'];
    $id2=$baris['id_user_tujuan'];
    $tanggal=$baris['tgl'];
    $awalan = substr($id1, 0,2);
    $awalan2 = substr($id2, 0,2);
    switch($awalan)
    {
        case 'ad':
            $name=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id_user = '$id1'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris2 = mysql_fetch_array ($name))
            {
                $nama2= $baris2['nama'];
            }
            break;

        case 'al':
            $name=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumni where id_user = '$id1'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris2 = mysql_fetch_array ($name))
            {
        $name2= $baris2['name'];
        $link_image=$baris2['foto'];

        $query_foto1 = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM alumni where foto = '$link_image'");
        $foto1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query_foto1);
        if($foto1 == "belum upload")
                       {
         $image = 'http://localhost/PortalAlumniSD/img/default.png';
          }
        else
        {
         $image = "http://localhost/PortalAlumniSD/photo/".$baris2['foto'];
                    }
            }
            break;

        case 'pd':
            $nama=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id_user = '$id1'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris2 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama))
            {
                $nama2= $baris2['nama'];
            }
            break;

        case 'pl':
            $nama=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumni where id_user = '$id1'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris2 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama))
            {
                $nama2= $baris2['nama'];
                $link_image=$baris2['foto'];

                $query_foto1 = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM alumni where foto = '$link_image'");
                    $foto1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query_foto1);
                    if($foto1 == "belum upload")
                       {
                       $image = 'http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMP/img/default.png';
                       }
                    else
                    {
                       $image = "http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMP/photo/".$baris2['foto'];
                    }
            }
            break;

        case 'md':
            $nama=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id_user = '$id1'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris2 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama))
            {
                $nama2= $baris2['nama'];
            }
            break;

        case 'ml':
            $nama=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumni where id_user = '$id1'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris2 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama))
            {
                //$data_status["nama_alumni"] = stripslashes($baris2["nama"]);
                $nama2= $baris2['nama'];
                //$data_status["nama_alumni"] = $nama2;
                $link_image=$baris2['foto'];

                $query_foto1 = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM alumni where foto = '$link_image'");
                    $foto1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query_foto1);
                    if($foto1 == "belum upload")
                       {
                       $image = 'http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMA/img/default.png';
                       }
                    else
                    {
                       $image = "http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMA/photo/".$baris2['foto'];
                    }
            }
            break;
    }

    switch($awalan2)
    {
        case 'ad':
            $nama_tujuan=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id_user = '$id2'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris_nama1 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama_tujuan))
            {
                $nama3= $baris_nama1['nama'];
            }
            break;

        case 'al':
            $nama_tujuan=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumni where id_user = '$id2'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris_nama1 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama_tujuan))
            {
                //$nama3= $baris_nama1['nama'];
                //$data_status["nama_alumni"] = $nama2;                 
                $nama3= $baris_nama1['nama'];
                //$data_status["nama_alumni_tujuan"] = $nama3;
                $link_image=$baris_nama1['foto'];

                $query_foto1 = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM alumni where foto = '$link_image'");
                    if($foto1 == "belum upload")
                       {
                       $image = 'http://localhost/PortalAlumniSD/img/default.png';
                       }
                    else
                    {
                       $image = "http://localhost/PortalAlumniSD/photo/".$baris2['foto'];
                    }
            }
            break;

        case 'pd':
            $nama_tujuan=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id_user = '$id2'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris_nama1 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama_tujuan))
            {
                $nama3= $baris_nama1['nama'];
            }
            break;

        case 'pl':
            $nama_tujuan=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumni where id_user = '$id2'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris_nama1 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama_tujuan))
            {           
                $nama3= $baris_nama1['nama'];
                $link_image=$baris_nama1['foto'];

                $query_foto1 = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM alumni where foto = '$link_image'");
                    $foto1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query_foto1);
                    if($foto1 == "belum upload")
                       {
                       $image = 'http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMP/img/default.png';
                       }
                    else
                    {
                       $image = "http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMP/photo/".$baris2['foto'];
                    }
            }
            break;

        case 'md':
            $nama_tujuan=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id_user = '$id2'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris_nama1 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama_tujuan))
            {
                $nama3= $baris_nama1['nama'];
            }
            break;

        case 'ml':
            $nama_tujuan=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alumni where id_user = '$id2'");
//        echo $nama;
            while($baris_nama1 = mysql_fetch_array ($nama_tujuan))
            {               
                $nama3= $baris_nama1['nama'];
                $link_image=$baris_nama1['foto'];

                $query_foto1 = mysql_query("SELECT foto FROM alumni where foto = '$link_image'");
                    $foto1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query_foto1);
                    if($foto1 == "belum upload")
                       {
                       $image = 'http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMA/img/default.png';
                       }
                    else
                    {
                       $image = "http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMA/photo/".$baris2['foto'];
                    }
            }
            break;

    }


    $jum=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM komen where id_status='$id_status'");
    $total= mysql_num_rows($jum);

    if($id1==$id2){
            $data_status["nama_alumni"] = $nama2;
            $data_status["link_image"] = $image;


    }else if($id1!=$id2){
            $data_status["nama_alumni"] = $nama2;
            $data_status["nama_alumni_tujuan"] = $nama3;
            $data_status["link_image"] = $image;

    }

        // temp user array $data_status = array();
        $data_status["id_user"] = $baris["id_user"]; 
        $data_status["id_status"] = $baris["id_status"]; 
        $data_status["id_user_tujuan"] = $baris["id_user_tujuan"]; 
        $data_status["status"] = stripslashes($baris["status"]);
        $data_status["date"] = stripslashes($baris["tgl"]); 
        $data_status["jml"] = $total;

        // menampilkan hasil query dalam bentuk array 
        array_push($response["data_status"], $data_status);
        }

        // success 
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response 
        echo json_encode($response);

    }else {
        // tidak ada data 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Tidak Ada Data";

        // echoing JSON response 
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Display json

```
{"data_status":[{"nama_alumni":"susa","link_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/PortalAlumniSMP\/photo\/","id_user":"plsusa@mail.com","id_status":"40","id_user_tujuan":"plsusa@mail.com","status":"ko","date":"April 2, 2014, 11:00 pm","jml":0,"nama_alumni_tujuan":"cumin"},{"nama_alumni":"susa","link_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/PortalAlumniSMP\/photo\/","id_user":"plsusa@mail.com","id_status":"36","id_user_tujuan":"plsusa@mail.com","status":"dfdsg","date":"April 2, 2014, 9:19 pm","jml":0,"nama_alumni_tujuan":"cumin"},{"nama_alumni":"cumin","link_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/PortalAlumniSD\/photo\/","id_user":"altest@mail.com","id_status":"35","id_user_tujuan":"alcandramarlina@ymail.com","status":"hhg","date":"April 2, 2014, 2:49 pm","jml":0,"nama_alumni_tujuan":"candra kasih"},{"nama_alumni":"cumin","link_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/PortalAlumniSD\/photo\/","id_user":"altest@mail.com","id_status":"33","id_user_tujuan":"alcandra.ratri@gmail.com","status":"","date":"April 2, 2014, 2:41 pm","jml":1,"nama_alumni_tujuan":"kasih"},{"nama_alumni":"cumin","link_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/PortalAlumniSD\/photo\/","id_user":"altest@mail.com","id_status":"29","id_user_tujuan":"alcandramarlina@ymail.com","status":"ayoo","date":"March 22, 2014, 6:49 am","jml":0,"nama_alumni_tujuan":"candra kasih"},{"nama_alumni":"kasih","link_image":"http:\/\/localhost\/PortalAlumniSD\/photo\/","id_user":"alcandra.ratri@gmail.com","id_status":"13","id_user_tujuan":"alcandra.ratri@gmail.com","status":"retertert","date":"March 5, 2014, 2:06 pm","jml":0,"nama_alumni_tujuan":"candra kasih"}],"success":1}
```

This code my app in android :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.portalalumni.LoginActivity.UserLoginTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] menuItems;
    private ArrayList<NsMenuItemModel> nsMenuItemModel;
    SessionManager session;

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Creating JSON Parser object 
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DataStatus;

        // url  
        private static String url_data_status = "http://10.0.2.2/alumni/status.php";

        // JSON Node names
        public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; 
        public static final String TAG_DATA_STATUS = "data_status"; 
        public static final String TAG_ID_USER = "id_user";
        public static final String TAG_ID_STATUS = "id_status";
        public static final String TAG_ID_USER_TUJUAN = "id_user_tujuan";
        public static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
        public static final String TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI = "nama_alumni";
        public static final String TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI_TUJUAN = "nama_alumni_tujuan";
        //public static final String TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI_TUJUAN3 = "nama_alumni_tujuan";
        public static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
        public static final String TAG_TOTAL = "jml";
        public static final String TAG_LINK_IMAGE = "link_image";
        public static final String TAG_LINK_IMAGE1 = "link_image1";

        // daftar_rs JSONArray 
        JSONArray data_status = null;
        ListView list;
        String id_user,email,success;
        ListStatus adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        session.checkLogin();

        //Hashmap from login
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
        id_user = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_IDUSER);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        DataStatus = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        // Loading daftar rumah sakit in Background Thread
        new LoadStatusActivity().execute();

        // Get listview
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(new ListStatus(this, DataStatus));

        // React to user clicks on item
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> selectedItem = DataStatus.get(position);
                   //To-DO get you data from the ItemDetails Getter
                  // selectedItem.get()
                  // the  send the data using intent when opening another activity 
                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CommentActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("id_status",selectedItem.get(TAG_ID_STATUS)); 
                  startActivity(intent);


            }
           });

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _initMenu();
        mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void _initMenu() {
        NsMenuAdapter mAdapter = new NsMenuAdapter(this);

        // Add first block

        menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.menu);
        String[] menuItemsIcon = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.menu_items_icon);

        nsMenuItemModel = new ArrayList<NsMenuItemModel>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        nsMenuItemModel.add(new NsMenuItemModel(menuItems[0], menuItemsIcon.length));
        nsMenuItemModel.add(new NsMenuItemModel(menuItems[1], menuItemsIcon.length));
        nsMenuItemModel.add(new NsMenuItemModel(menuItems[2], menuItemsIcon.length));
        nsMenuItemModel.add(new NsMenuItemModel(menuItems[2], menuItemsIcon.length));

        int res = 0;
        for (String item : menuItems) {

            int id_title = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "string",
                    this.getPackageName());
            int id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(menuItemsIcon[res],
                    "drawable", this.getPackageName());

            NsMenuItemModel mItem = new NsMenuItemModel(id_title, id_icon);
            //if (res==1) mItem.counter=12; //it is just an example...
            //if (res==3) mItem.counter=3; //it is just an example...
            mAdapter.addItem(mItem);
            res++;
        }

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (mDrawerList != null)
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_new_status).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        /*
         * The action bar home/up should open or close the drawer.
         * ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
         */
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

                // Handle action bar actions click
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_search:
                    search();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_new_status:
                    newstatus();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
    }

    private void newstatus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = null;
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewStatusActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    private void search() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = null;
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchAlumniActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    private void profile() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = null;
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    private void home() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = null;
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    private void inbox() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = null;
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InboxActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }

    private void logout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        session.logoutUser();
        finish();
    }

    private class CustomActionBarDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity mActivity,DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout){
            super(
                mActivity,
                mDrawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.menu_open, 
                R.string.menu_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_close));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.menu_open));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                profile();
                break;
            case 1:
                home();
                break;
            case 2:
                inbox();
                break;
            case 3:
                logout();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }

    }

    public static void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            if (view.getBackground() != null) {
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
                try {
                    ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
                } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                    // No problem, nothing to do here
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /***    Updating parsed JSON data into ListView *   */ 
    public void SetListViewAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> status) {
        adapter = new ListStatus(this, status); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {

        //  if result code 100 is received 
        //  means user edited/deleted record 
        //  reload this screen again 

        Intent intent = getIntent(); 
        finish(); 
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    /***    Background Async Task to Load all record data by making HTTP Request *  */ 
    class LoadStatusActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /***    Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog *    */ 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading..."); 
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /***    getting All record data from url *  */ 

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    // Building Parameters 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    // getting JSON string from URL 
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_data_status, "GET", params);

    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse 
        Log.d("Status: ", json.toString());

    try {
    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

    if (success == 1) {
        //  Ada record Data (SUCCESS = 1) 
        //  Getting Array of data_alumni 
        data_status = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA_STATUS);

    // looping through All data_alumni
    for (int i = 0; i < data_status.length(); i++) { 
        JSONObject c = data_status.getJSONObject(i);

        //  Storing each json item in variable 
        String id_user = c.getString(TAG_ID_USER);
        String id_status = c.getString(TAG_ID_STATUS);
        String id_user_tujuan = c.getString(TAG_ID_USER);
        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
        String jml = c.getString(TAG_TOTAL);
        String nama_alumni = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI);
        String nama_alumni_tujuan = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI_TUJUAN);
        //String nama_alumni_tujuan3 = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI_TUJUAN3);
        String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
        String link_image = c.getString(TAG_LINK_IMAGE); 
        String link_image1 = c.getString(TAG_LINK_IMAGE1); 


        //  creating new HashMap 
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

        //  adding each child node to HashMap key => value 
        map.put(TAG_ID_USER, id_user);
        map.put(TAG_ID_STATUS, id_status);
        map.put(TAG_ID_USER_TUJUAN, id_user_tujuan); 
        map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
        map.put(TAG_TOTAL, jml);
        map.put(TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI, nama_alumni);
        map.put(TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI_TUJUAN, nama_alumni_tujuan);
        //map.put(TAG_NAMA_ALUMNI_TUJUAN3, nama_alumni_tujuan3);
        map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
        map.put(TAG_LINK_IMAGE, link_image);
        map.put(TAG_LINK_IMAGE1, link_image1);

        //  adding HashList to ArrayList 
        DataStatus.add(map);

    }
    } else {
        //  Tidak Ada Record Data (SUCCESS = 0) 
        super.onCancelled();
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }

    /***    After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog *  **/ 
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all record data alumni
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // updating listview 
            SetListViewAdapter(DataStatus);

        }
        });
    }
    }

    /**@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    } **/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the json, this is your image's URL: `http://localhost/PortalAlumniSMP/photo/`.
It is referring to localhost, so it will probably work on your PC (assuming it is also your web server). It would not work on the Android device though.

Localhost refers to the current device - i.e. when you open it via your desktop browse it looks for the image on your PC (and it is indeed there). When you open it via the smartphone it looks for the image on the gsm only - not your PC. Thus it can't find it.

You need to publish your web application somewhere - either host it on your own web server or use some hosting provider / cloud service. Then refer to the images via the domain name instead of "localhost".

Comment: thanks for replying but I just simulate with android using wifi so still on localhost. I confused, why the image location is always read when condition else, besides if condition true

Comment: hm, what do you mean by simulating the android using wifi? :) Could you also share some of your Android code, since I'm a little confused what is happening.

Comment: I still think you should change the "localhost" value. Can you try with "10.0.2.2" - the same way you use it to call the php file.

Comment: ok thank you. it's work.. but if($foto1 == "not upload"){
$image = "http://10.0.2.2/PortalAlumniSMA/img/default.png";} can't display in json.